# Is it possible to get browser market share by OS?

Tags: browsers, statistics, operating-system

For development purposes, I'd like to get a rough estimate of the distribution of browser usage share, but everything I've been able to find just states overall market share. Is it possible to get browser share by OS?

Comment: I thought this would be easy to find. Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Here you go : http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp

Comment: @AgA There are just OS stats, not browsers grouped by OS.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this on a case by case basis per client. If you are developing a new site for them I would look at the analytics data of their existing site to determine the browser by OS of their existing target audience and then develop the new site accordingly.

I don't know of any existing data sources that show this in general although I am sure they exist somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [NetMarketShare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=0) and filter by Operating System at the top. Note that you need to subscribe to paid "Geolocation Upgrade".